# Angular: How to Select 2 Radio Buttons between 2 Radio Groups in Material?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material

This is my component form:

```
<div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 mb-2">
    <mat-radio-group aria-label="Select an option" formControlName="gender">
        <mat-radio-button [value]="true" [checked]="false" name="male">Male</mat-radio-button>
        <mat-radio-button [value]="false" [checked]="false" name="famale">Famale</mat-radio-button>
    </mat-radio-group>
    <mat-radio-group aria-label="Select an option" formControlName="name">
        <mat-radio-button [value]="false" [checked]="false"  name="benjamin">Benjamin</mat-radio-button>
        <mat-radio-button [value]="true" [checked]="false"  name="sarah">Sarah</mat-radio-button>
    </mat-radio-group>
</div>
```

I want to achieve something like this:

[image: If i select the gender the name should be selected automatically refering to the current selected gender]

[image]

i.e. if I select the gender, the name referring to the currently selected gender should be automatically selected.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 mb-2">
    <mat-radio-group aria-label="Select an option" formControlName="gender">
        <mat-radio-button [value]="true" [checked]="false" name="male">Male</mat-radio-button>
        <mat-radio-button [value]="false" [checked]="false" name="famale">Famale</mat-radio-button>
    </mat-radio-group>
    <mat-radio-group aria-label="Select an option" formControlName="name">
        <mat-radio-button [value]="true" [checked]="form.controls['gender'].value === true" name="benjamin">Benjamin</mat-radio-button>
        <mat-radio-button [value]="false" [checked]="form.controls['gender'].value === false" name="sarah">Sarah</mat-radio-button>
    </mat-radio-group>
</div>
```

Comment: We should not use checked and formControlName together (when we use formControlName, is the value of the FormControl who makes the radio is checked or not). So the correct is remove the `[checked]` in the first mat-radio-group and the `formControlName` in the second one. Yes to have a FormControl "name" is unnecesary -always get's the same value than the FormControl "gender"-

Comment: Can you show me a live example on https://stackblitz.com/